# Как определить, когда заставка на компьютере может быть включена при бездействии пользователя и отсутствии активных процессов?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms

Как определить, когда заставка на компьютере может быть включена при бездействии пользователя и отсутствии активных процессов?

Перед тем как включается заставка, должны быть соблюдены некоторые условия:

1. время, когда заставка должна быть включена;
2. бездействия пользователя;
3. отсутствия активных процессов, таких как: воспроизведение видео, звука или игры и.т.д.

Вопрос: Меня интересует, как именно можно определить, соблюдаются ли условия номер 2 и 3 или не соблюдаются. Как можно это сделать? Как это определяет windows?

К примеру, PowerManager определяет это с помощью команды

```
powercfg /requests
```

но у неё нет API.

А как это определяется в заставках, может быть есть API относительно этой функции?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, Вам подойдут 2 функции из `Win32 API`:

- `SystemParametersInfo`
- `GetLastInputInfo`

С помощью первой функции можно определить, не выполняется ли в данный момент скринсейвер; можно узнать, через какое время бездействия будет запущен скринсейвер; и многое другое...

Представляет интерес тот факт, что видеопроигрыватели и игры часто устанавливают в системе флаг `SPI_SETSCREENSAVERRUNNING`, чтобы предотвратить запуск скринсейвера.

Так что, целенаправленно отслеживать наличие в системе запущенного видеопроигрывателя или игры нет нужды (возможно, за исключением каких-то специфических случаев). Достаточно проверять флаг `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING`.

Вторая функция возвращает время последнего пользовательского ввода (мышь, клавиатура, др. устройства ввода), в том же формате, что функция GetTickCount().

Пример кода:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU-ru");

    BOOL is_screensaver_running;
    if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &is_screensaver_running, 0))
    {
        if (!is_screensaver_running)
        {
            ULONG screensaver_timeout;
            if (SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, 0, &screensaver_timeout, 0))
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    LASTINPUTINFO info;
                    ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(info));
                    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);

                    if (GetLastInputInfo(&info))
                    {
                        ULONGLONG diff = (GetTickCount() - info.dwTime) / 1000;
                        cout << "LAST_INPUT был примерно " << diff << " сек. тому назад;  до запуска скринсейвера осталось: " << (screensaver_timeout - diff) << " сек." << endl;
                    }

                    Sleep(2000);
                }
        }
        else
            cout << "Скринсейвер уже выполняется" << endl;
    }
}
```

Ссылки на MSDN:

- функция SystemParametersInfo: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa
- функция GetLastInputInfo: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo

Comment: Благодарю, но сомневаюсь, что это подойдёт. Мне бы подошла функция или алгоритм, который используется в windows для заставки. А как это определяется в заставках, может быть есть API относительно этой функции?